# PickSaveFileAndContinue: UnauthorizedAccessException on Windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-dev-center

I am using this code to let users to choose where to save a file:

```
        var fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Pdf", new List<string>(){".pdf"});
        fileSavePicker.SuggestedFileName = $"{pdfFile.Name}";
        fileSavePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = pdfFile;
        fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue();
```

This code works fine on Windows Phone 8.1 but give me an exception (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) when running on Windows 10 mobile. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I use **FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue** method in the visual, there is an error **“ The FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue() is obsolete: instead, use PickSaveFileAsync() ”.** So you can use [**FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.picksavefileasync) method in Windows 10 mobile.

[image]

**Update:**
I have test Windows Phone 8.1 on Windows 10 Mobile, it was ok. The code of my project below , you can refer to.

You can also refer to this sample about [**FileSavePicker**](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba/sourcecode?fileId=43705&pathId=1155535444).

```
 private void SaveFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear previous returned file name, if it exists, between iterations of this scenario
        OutputTextBlock.Text = "";

        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        // Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
        // Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";

        savePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle the returned file from file picker
    /// This method is triggered by ContinuationManager based on ActivationKind
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">File save picker continuation activation argment. It cantains the file user selected with file save picker </param>
    public async void ContinueFileSavePicker(FileSavePickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        StorageFile file = args.File;
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
            // write to file
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, file.Name);
            // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
            // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
            FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
            if (status == FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
            {
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " + file.Name + " was saved.";
            }
            else
            {
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " + file.Name + " couldn't be saved.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I test my Windows Phone 8.1 project on Windows 10 Mobile, it is ok. you can refer to my update in response for more information.

Comment: Thanks I think the problem was this line in wich pdfFile is a StorageFile: 
 `fileSavePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = pdfFile;` 
infact in your example you make same things except this.